# merge two multidimensional array based on same ID

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am facing one issue when merging two multidimensional arrays based on the same ID.

In the example below I created two arrays - `Array1` and `Array2`. Both arrays contain objects that have an `ID` property. Based on the `ID` property, the arrays should be merged and get the result array:

Array1

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [claimtotal] => 
        [total] => 4
        [ID] => 3

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [claimtotal] => 20
        [total] => 1
        [ID] => 4
    )
)
```

Array2

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =>2 
        [name] => test1

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [name] => test2
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =>4 
        [name] => test3
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5
        [name] => test4
    )
)
```

Result_array

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =>2 
        [name] => test1
        [claimtotal] => 
        [total] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [name] => test2
        [claimtotal] => 
        [total] => 4
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =>4 
        [name] => test3
        [claimtotal] => 20
        [total] => 1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5
        [name] => test4
        [claimtotal] => 
        [total] => 
    )
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in order to get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if these are simple objects without methods go:

```
foreach($firstArray as $key => $firstObject){
foreach($secondArray as $secondObject){
    if($firstObject['id'] === $secondObject['id']){
        $firstArray[$key] = (object) array_merge((array) $firstObject, (array) $secondObject);
    }               
  }
}
```

looks messy but does the job without introducing another loop to go through object properties.